# User permits on cmdkey to execute remotely

Tags: powershell, permissions, powershell-remoting, credential-manager

Ive made an script to re-add credentials on windows, the script locally works fine, but when i try to execute via Invoke-Command the script just executes itself and does nothing or via Enter-Pssesion and executing it manually the options of the script popup but still,the data that should pass form cmdkey /list doesnt get stored on the txts so the script does nothing. I understand that if use a credential(user A) in INVCOMM/ENTPSS i cant see the credentials of the user B that is currently logged in the pc.

Ive tried connecting via Enter-pssesion (user A) and execute the command cmdkey /list alone but the result of the command is "i dont have stored credentials " even tho im logged locally on the pc as user A and i see the 2 credentials stored. If i execute cmdkey /delete it gives me the error "a specified login session does not exist", /add says that i cannot store the credentials through this startup session.

Im 90% sure that its my user permits (im admin "user A") but i dont know where to start to check for it.

```
$salidacom = cmdkey /list

#FILTRAMOS POR DESTINO/USUARIO
$salidacom | Select-String "Destino" | Out-File "C:\InC\p1.txt" -Force
$salidacom | Select-String "Usuario" | Out-File "C:\InC\p2.txt" -Force
    
#FILTRAMOS LA SALIDA SERVIDORES
$SERVI1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\InC\p1.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match "X.X.X.X" }
$SERVI2 = Get-Content -Path "C:\InC\p1.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match "Y.Y.Y.Y" }

Write-Host "$SERVI1 $SERVI2"

$TXTUSU = "C:\InC\p3.txt"
$USUSRAW = Get-Content -Path "C:\InC\p2.txt"
#FILTRAMOS SOLO LO DE LA DE DERECHA DE USUARIO:
$usufilt = 'Usuario: (.+)'

#ARRAY PARA GUARDAR LOS USUARIOS
$USUCORT = @()

foreach ($linea in $USUSRAW) {
    #MIRAMOS LINEA POR LINEA PARA SACAR CON EL FILTRO
    if ($linea -match $usufilt) {
        #SE SACAN LOS USUS
        $USUTOT = $matches[1]
        #METEMOS LOS USUARIOS AL ARRAY PARA QUE NOS CUENTE COMO VALORES PARA EXTRAERLO
        $USUCORT += $USUTOT

    }
}

$USUCORT | Out-File -FilePath $TXTUSU -Force

#FILTRAMOS LOS USU DE CREDENCIALES ESTABLECEMOS UNA VARIABLE POR USUARIO

$USUCORT = Get-Content -Path "C:\InC\p3.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match "XXXX.COM\\*" }
$contador = 1
foreach($USUSOLO IN $USUCORT){
    New-Variable -Name "Usu$contador" -Value $USUSOLO -Force
$contador++
}

Write-Host "$Usu1 $Usu2"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

#ELIM CREDENCIAL

$resp = Read-Host "¿Quieres eliminar la credencial(si/no)?"

if ($resp -eq "Si" -or $resp -eq "si") {
    $serv = Read-host "Dime cual quieres quitar. 1=X.X.X.X 2=Y.Y.Y.Y"
        if ($serv -eq "1"){
            $servidor = "X.X.X.X"
            cmdkey /delete:$servidor
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        }
-----------

#AGREG CREDENCIAL

$resp = Read-Host "¿Quieres agregar una credencial(si/no)?"

if ($resp -eq "Si" -or $resp -eq "si") {
    $serv = Read-host "Dime cual de los servidores es el que quieres añadir. 1=X.X.X.X 2=Y.Y.Y.Y"

#PARA EL X.X.X.X

    if ($serv -eq "1"){
        $servidor1 = "X.X.X.X"
            $opc = Read-Host "¿Quieres usar los usuarios que tenia (T) o nuevos (N)?"

            if ($opc -eq "T" -or $opc -eq "t"){
                $usuexist = Read-Host = "Te muestro las credenciales existentes (1)$SERVI1 (2)$SERVI2 | $USUCORT "
                    if ($usuexist -eq 1 ){    
                    $pass = Read-Host -Prompt "Dime la contrasena" -AsSecureString
                    cmdkey /add:$servidor1 /user:$Usu1 /pass:$pass
                    
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                    }
----------
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears not to be related to *permissions* or privileges, but to the fact that **[`cmdkey.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey) currently does *not* to work from a session that has no [*window station*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations) associated with it** (loosely speaking, a session *without a desktop*), which indeed **applies to PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) sessions**.

- [This comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23328#issuecomment-458236481) in the GitHub repo for the Azure documentation suggests that there is *no* good technical reason for `cmdkey.exe` to require this and that it **may change in the future, but the requirement is still in place as of Windows 11 22H2**.
  The workarounds suggested in other comments on the same issue didn't work for me.

---

**Potential alternative / workaround**:

As an alternative to `cmdkey.exe`, consider switching to the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules) module with the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretstore/?view=ps-modules) with the local-file-system vault extension module, which *can* be used via PowerShell remoting:

- Note that - unlike `cmdkey.exe` - this storage mechanism does *not* integrate with Windows Credential Manager.
- It furthermore assumes that these module are installed on the *target* machine(s), though it *is* possible to install them *remotely*; e.g.:

```bash
$computer = 'computer1' # Specify the target computer here.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer { 

  # Install the modules, if needed
  if (-not (Get-Module -List Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore)) {
    Install-Module -ErrorAction Stop -Scope AllUsers Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore
  }

  # If not already registered, register a local vault and make it the default vault
  $localVault = 'LocalVault'
  if (-not (Get-SecretVault -ErrorAction Ignore $localVault)) {
    # This will prompt for a password for the vault as a whole.
    Register-SecretVault -ErrorAction Stop -Name $localVault -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault
  } else {
    # Unlock the local vault:
    # When prompted, provide the previously chosen password.
    Unlock-SecretStore -ErrorAction Stop
  }

  # Now you can use Set-Secret to store a secret in the local vault
  # that you can later retrieve with Get-Secret; e.g.:
  Set-Secret server1 (Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Enter password for server1')

}
```